# json.net All properties written to JsonExtensionData instead of to actual object properties

Tags: json.net

I have a base class with JsonExtensionData, lets assume

```
class AType {
    public AType()  { _additionalData = new Dictionary<string, JToken>(); }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;
}
```

and a class B that extends A with other properties

```
class BType : AType {
    public int N { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

when Deserializing an Array of B objects into a **`List<BType>`** all values will go into the **`_additionalData`** and not to the correct properties i.e **`N`** and **`Name`**. the same problem happens with **`JObject.ToObject(Type)`** and **`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Type)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... and i'ts my problem.  Sorry about this you can close the issue. 
In my application i have lots of classes and first i've tried to use the default .net json converter but I've forgot to remove DataContractAttribute on 2 of the class when i've changed to use json.net library and thouse where the classes giving problems in `BType`

Comment: Thank you for coming back to post your answer!